# Change product price when option selected in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm developing a module that appears in the product page. This module consist of a checkbox which when is checked, shows a few inputs to be filled by the client and add an extra amount of, for example, 50.

How can I add this amount to the product cart? I'm using the hook `hookActionCartSave` to retrieve the cart but I can't update it adding the amount of 50.

The ideal is to reflex this concept like shipping costs but I'm stuck on how to change the product price or add a new concept when the checkbox is checked and client click "Add to cart" button.

Thank you!

Comment: my guess would be to create a `specific_price` with the current `cart_id` to add this amount on fly

Comment: Thanks chandlerbing. I tried that but didn't work although I did not try to hard because I didn't know if that was the right path. I will try again.